# Cannot extract the description and rating while scraping using requests and Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm a beginner to web scraping, I was scraping this particular web page https://myanimelist.net/anime/394 where I was unable to fetch the description and rating though my python code using requests and Beautiful Soup. The code is working fine for the other pages of the above url indexes. Can't find the bug in my code when the same code is working for other pages.

My progress so far in the code is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


url="https://myanimelist.net/anime/394"
source=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(source.content,'lxml')


def info_anime(soup):

    #Extracting the name of the anime

    anime=soup.find(name="span",attrs={"itemprop":"name"})
    name=anime.text
    print ("Anime : "+name)

    #Extracting the rating 

    rating=soup.find(name="div",attrs={"class":"fl-l score"})
    print ("Rating : "+(rating.text.strip()))


    #extracting the description

    des=soup.find(name="span",attrs={"itemprop":"description"})
    description=des.text
    print ("Description : "+description)

    #Extracting the Rank

    rank=soup.find(name="span",attrs={"class":"numbers ranked"})
    print (rank.text)

    #Extracting number of episodes

    ep=soup.find(name="div",attrs={"class":"spaceit"})
    print (ep.text)

print (info_anime(soup))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change:

```
soup=BeautifulSoup(source.content,'lxml')
```

to:

```
soup=BeautifulSoup(source.content,'html.parser')
```

when I changed that, I got the output:

```
Anime : Ai Yori Aoshi: Enishi
Rating : 7.22
Description : Two years after meeting Aoi, Kaoru and gang are still up to their normal habits. Kaoru now in grad school and the tenants being as rowdy as ever what will become of Aoi and Kaoru's love.

Two years has passed since Aoi and Kaoru were freed from the bonds of their families. They continue to live their normal lives with their usual friends in their house.
Ranked #2737

Episodes:
  12

None
```